# How to only scrape link from webpage - Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

My goal is to get each link

My code prints the href/link, however it also prints other junk which i do not want.

I only want the href/

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import requests
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
productlink=[]
for x in range (1,3):
    driver.get(f'https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/browse-meetings/2021%20Gastrointestinal%20Cancers%20Symposium?page={x}')
    time.sleep(3)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
    productlist=soup.find_all('div',class_='session')
    for item in productlist:
        for link in item.find_all('a',class_='session__button ng-star-inserted',href=True):
            print(link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `href=True` means get those tags with `href` attribute.There are still `Tag`. To get the `href`, you also need to use `.get("href")`.Since there is only one button in each `session` tag, you could use `find` instead of `find_all`,and don't forget to join the `baseURL`.Try code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import requests
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
productlink=[]
baseURL = 'https://meetinglibrary.asco.org'
for x in range (1,3):
    driver.get(f'https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/browse-meetings/2021%20Gastrointestinal%20Cancers%20Symposium?page={x}')
    time.sleep(3)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
    productlist=soup.find_all('div',class_='session')
    for item in productlist:
        print(baseURL + item.find('a',class_='session__button ng-star-inserted',href=True).get("href"))
```

Print:

```
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13455
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13458
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13445
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13450
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13460
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13462
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13464
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13459
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13446
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13451
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13461
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13463
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13465
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13399
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13443
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13444
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13352
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13381
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13383
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13372
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13382
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13447
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13849
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13384
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13389
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13453
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13859
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13391
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13392
https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13394
....
```